# How can you generate a list of N sorted keys of a hashmap, sorting by value?

Tags: c#, java, sorting, hashmap

I'm not very familiar with Java, and I'm a bit unsure of how to translate this from c# into java.

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = GetDictionary();
int N = 10;

myDictionary
         .OrderByDescending(dictionaryEntry => dictionaryEntry.Value)
         .Take(N)
         .Select(dictionaryEntry => dictionaryEntry.Key)
         .ToList();
```

Now, I KNOW the dictionary itself isnt being sorted, its just a new IEnumberable, and that's OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C# guy, I've never worked with it, but if I should take a guess it seems like you are sorting the map by its values in descending order, retrieving the 10 first elements, then converting the keys of those 10 elements into a list.

If the values are known to be distinct, then it's kind of trivial - you just convert to a SortedMap with keys and values exchanged. So I'm assuming that the values are not distinct, i.e. that the same number may appear multiple times.

In that case it's not as trivial, and definitely not as simple as in your C# example. My first thought was to create a sorted set with a custom comparator, where each element in the set is a Map.Entry from your map, where the keys and values are exchanged.

This will actually require quite a bit of code in Java. Heres one attempt:

```
// Create a SortedSet of the reversed entry set, with a custom comparator for sorting
SortedSet<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>(
        new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>() {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, String> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, String> o2) {
        // sort by key, then by value --> in descending order
        int keyCompareResult = -o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()); // negate --> descending
        int valueCompareResult = o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        return keyCompareResult == 0 ? valueCompareResult : -keyCompareResult;
    }
});

// Add all entries of the map to the sorted set
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> reversedEntry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, String>(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    sortedSet.add(reversedEntry);
}

// Convert the 10 first elements to the resulting list
int N = 10;
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(N);
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> iterator = sortedSet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext() && result.size() < N) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = iterator.next();
    result.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! After searching for a bit I ended doing something similar, but I didn't know of the SortedSet class so I made an 

ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>

implemented a little class for the Comparator, and then used 

Collections.sort(myArrayList, Collections.reverseOrder(new MapEntryComparator()));

For selecting the Top N elements, its pretty much the same but with a for.

I'll add my answer for completeness, but its pretty much the same as yours, so I'll give you the answer :)

Comment: Though if anybody knows of a more LINQ-y / functional way to do it, please add the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with pretty much the same thing as Steinar suggested, if you know of a more LINQ-y/functional way to do it, please add your answer too!

```
//Convert to List of Map.Entry
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> myArrayList = ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(myHashMap.entrySet());

//Natural order is ascending, so we reverse the comparator to get it Descending.
Collections.sort(myArrayList , Collections.reverseOrder(new EntryComparator()));

//Create list and add Keys

List<String> topNStrings =  new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < N && i < myArrayList.size(); i++)
{
  topNStrings.add(myArrayList.get(i).getKey());
}
```

and had a separate little comparator class

```
private class EntryComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>
    {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String,Integer> x, Map.Entry<String,Integer> y)
    {
        return compare(x.getValue(), y.getValue());
    }

    private int compare(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        return a < b ? -1
                : a > b ? 1
                : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let us start with an arbitrary HashMap that you have acquired somehow defined by `HashMap<String, Integer> map`.

We want to sort the **values** and then get the first `N` values.

```
int N = 10;

List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>( map.values() );
Collections.sort(values);
List<Integer> N_values = values.subList(0, N);
```

Comment: This is sorting the the hashmap by the Keys (strings), not by the values